# Which is the correct Twin T Notch Filter design?

Tags: filter

Which is the correct Twin T Notch Filter design?

[image]

I found a Twin T Notch Filter disign, but the circuit is not very clear, I add some details to it. And then I am a bit confuse about the connection under R4 and R5, should it be GND or V-?